# powermock contains() not working

Tags: java, testing, mocking, powermock

I am trying to mock an http call using PowerMockito, but I am having some problems with the `contains()` function.
My plan is to check if the path contains a certain string and then I return the mock object.
So I have the following function:

```
import static com.mscharhag.oleaster.runner.StaticRunnerSupport.*;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.internal.verification.VerificationModeFactory.times;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;
private static <T> void mockResponse(Class<T> type, T response, String pathContains) throws Exception
{
    mockStatic(ClientBuilder.class);
    Client client = mock(Client.class);
    when(ClientBuilder.class, "newClient").thenReturn(client);
    WebTarget webTarget = mock(WebTarget.class);
    when(client.target(anyString())).thenReturn(webTarget);

    //This is what doesn't work
    when(webTarget.path(contains(pathContains))).thenReturn(webTarget);

    when(webTarget.queryParam(any(), any())).thenReturn(webTarget);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = mock(Invocation.Builder.class);
    when(webTarget.request()).thenReturn(invocationBuilder);
    Invocation invocation = mock(Invocation.class);
    when(invocationBuilder.buildGet()).thenReturn(invocation);

    Response res = mock(Response.class);
    when(invocation.invoke()).thenReturn(res);
    when(res.readEntity(type)).thenReturn(response);
}

mockResponse(GenreList.class, new GenreList(new Genre(0, "g")), "genre");
```

Problem is that I get a nullpointer when I am trying to make an HTTP call:

```
    Response res = client.target(theMovieDbURL)
                         .path("/3/genre/movie/list")
                         .queryParam("api_key", apiKey)
                         .request()
                         .buildGet()
                         .invoke();
```

If I where to change the mock from `contains()` to `anyString()` it works like a charm, but I need to have different responses for different paths, so I can't leave it as `anyString()`. I've tried changing it to `eq()` as well, but it doesn't work either.

What is it that I am missing here?

from my gradle:

```
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.6.6'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version: '1.6.6'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4-rule', version: '1.6.6'
```

Comment: Please provide the mock preparation part of your test. There is no call to `mockResponse` in the code you have shared.

Comment: @AlehMaksimovich it is there now :)

Comment: The only idea I have right now that you may be using some wrong `contains`. Can you add your static imports section?

Comment: The interesting part is that I can't reproduce your issue. Everything works for me as `when(webTarget1.path(contains("genre"))).thenReturn(webTarget1);` as well as `doReturn(webTarget2).when(webTarget2).path(contains("genre"));` and `when(webTarget3.path(matches(".*genre.*"))).thenReturn(webTarget3);`. Last question what version of PowerMock and Mockito you are using?

Comment: That is really wierd... I've attached parts from my gradle file. what version are you using?

Comment: For my local tests here I have added powermock-api-mockito 1.6.3 as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

More of a non-answer: you are going down the wrong rabbit hole here.

Thing is: the purpose of a *test* is to ensure that **specific** production code implements that requirement that a test is supposed to cover. Nothing else.

Leading to: you prefer multiple simple, straight forward tests over one single piece of code that is able to handle many different aspects.

Meaning: you do not go and start using

```
when(webTarget.path(contains(pathContains))).thenReturn(webTarget);
```

where you have various different possibilities what contains() might see. Instead, you rather have n tests that explicitly say

```
when(webTarget.path(contains(A))).thenReturn(webTargetA);
```

...

```
when(webTarget.path(contains(B))).thenReturn(webTargetB);
```

In other words: you intend to somehow express clever "business logic" within your test code. You want to make it "smart". Don't do that. Instead focus on writing test code that is, as said, **straight forward** creating a specific setup, to then test for **one** thing.

In yet other words: there should be **no** need in your test code to provide *parameter* specific return values. Because **you** define the setup (and thereby the paths) that your production code will see. You tell it to take path A for one test, and path B in another test. And then your desire to have elaborate if/then logic vanishes in thin air.